# Python: replacing filenames

Tags: python-2.7

I need your help desperately. I've heard python is user friendly but I am having difficult time trying to figure out the right commands.

I have file names as:

```
cake_cake01_F_A01.ab1 
cake_cake02_F_A02.ab1 
cake_cake03_F_A03.ab1 
cake_cake04_F_B01.ab1 
cake_cake05_F_B02.ab1 
cake_cake06_F_B03.ab1 
cake_cake07_F_C01.ab1 
cake_cake08_F_C02.ab1 
cake_cake09_F_C03.ab1
```

in a folder with a specific directory.

I need to change them to:

```
cake_cake01-2101plus.ab1  
cake_cake02-2101plus.ab1 
cake_cake03-2101plus.ab1 
cake_cake04-2101plus.ab1 
cake_cake05-2101plus.ab1 
cake_cake06-2101plus.ab1
cake_cake07-2101plus.ab1 
cake_cake08-2101plus.ab1 
cake_cake09-2101plus.ab1
```

in the same folder.

I guess I have to delete -10 to -5 positions of those names and add `-2010plus` before the file extension. How can I do this using Python?

Comment: I tried to use full directory using old='_F_A01' and new='-2101plus' and using os.rename(full directory of each file, rename(old, new)). But this case I had to assign the full directory of each file which is not practical since I have hundreds of files named like above.... I hope I am explaining it well....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not use `glob` to get the filenames to change:

```
import os
import glob

filenames = glob.glob('/path/to/cake_cake*.ab1')
for filename in filenames:
    newname = filename[:-10] + '-2101plus.ab1'
    os.rename(filename, newname)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.

Using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) you can `match()` a needed pattern, and then create a new name from previous string by substituting only the part of the string you wish.

You can easily change `replacement`, or iterate over all directories (`directory`) if needed, or even change the start or end of pattern.

Short explanation of the pattern: `\d{2}` means "2 digits", `\.` matches the dot, `[A-Z]` matches any capital letter.

```
import os
import re

################ Change those ###############
replacement = '-2101plus'
directory = '/home/usercat/allmycakes'

first_part_of_pattern = 'cake_cake\d{2}'
last_part_of_pattern = 'txt'
#############################################

for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
    if re.match(r'%s_[A-Z]_[A-Z]\d{2}\.%s' % (first_part_of_pattern, last_part_of_pattern), file_name):

        old_path = directory + '/' + file_name
        new_file_name = re.sub(r'(%s)_[A-Z]_[A-Z]\d{2}(\.%s)' % (first_part_of_pattern, last_part_of_pattern),
                               r'\1{}\2'.format(replacement), file_name)

        new_path = directory + '/' + new_file_name

        os.renames(old_path, new_path)
```